# 'Extra argument in call' when passing arguments to my method

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

I have two functions in my class. The compiler is complaining about the function that calls the other. It's always complaining about the second argument, so if I delete the second argument, it will complain about the new second argument. I have also tried removing all arguments but the first, and it tells me "Cannot convert value of type '' to expected argument type 'SaveImages' ". SaveImages is the name of my class. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code: (I can include more code if it's necessary)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class SaveImages: NSObject {

func saveData(originalImageData: NSData, resizedImageData: NSData, imageID: Int, filterID: Int) {
  //function code
}

class func saveImage(imageData: NSData, filterID: Int) { 
  //function code (sets variables for the arguments)

    saveData(original, resizedImageData: resized, imageID: id, filterID: filter) //error here

    }
}
```

Comment: `saveData` is not a class function, so it must be called on an instance of `SaveData`  You can't just call it from a class function

Comment: Oh. I see. Thanks you have answered my question. I'll post the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I wasn't calling the function on an instance of SaveImages, because saveData isn't a class function, but I was trying to call it from a class function.

I changed this:

```
saveData(original, resizedImageData: resized, imageID: id, filterID: filter)
```

to this:

```
SaveImages().saveData(original, resizedImageData: resized, imageID: id, filterID: filter)
```

And everything works well now. Thank you Paulw11 for your comment.